# Java JDBC Connection Pooling (How to check)?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling

First of all, I'm new to `Java/JSP/Eclipse`. However, I've many many years of .Net experience. I have just learned in Java how to make a connection to MS SQL Server using the `javax.sql.DataSource` (so that I don't need to key in the userid/password).

Right now, I've created a class to handle DB query, and in that class, I have a function that I can just call to return a `RowSet`.

```
    import javax.naming.Context;
    import javax.naming.InitialContext;
    import java.sql.Connection;

    import javax.sql.DataSource;
    import javax.sql.rowset.JdbcRowSet;
    import com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl;

    public abstract class ClsDBAccessBASE {
        public boolean prbAutoCommit = true;
        public String prsDataSourceName = "";

            public ClsDBAccessBASE( String pvsDataSourceName ) {
                    prsDataSourceName = pvsDataSourceName;
            }
            public JdbcRowSet fnorsSQLText( String pvsSQLText ) {
                JdbcRowSet voRS = null;

                try {
                    Context voContext = new InitialContext();
                    DataSource voDS = (DataSource)voContext.lookup(prsDataSourceName);
                    Connection voConn = (Connection)voDS.getConnection();
                    voRS = new JdbcRowSetImpl((voConn.createStatement()).executeQuery(pvsSQLText));
                } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

                return voRS;
            }
        }
    }
```

My objective is to ensure that I am using Connection Pooling. I understand that the `JdbcRowSet` implements that automatically?  However, the problem (I think) is that I am casting the `(voConn.createStatement()).executeQuery(pvsSQLText)` from a `ResultSet` to a `JdbcRowSet`. Would this mean that the underlying connection used is still `ResultSet`? and not `RowSet`?
Is there a way for me to check that I am indeed using Connection Pooling?

I'm sorry, if my question sounds silly. I am very new to Java development & Eclipse. Please bear with me and I will appreciate any guidance you can provide me.

I am using: `sqljdbc4.jar` from `Microsoft` (which seems to give me error whenever I call the `JdbcRowSet.execute()` function and/or .next() function. Something about NullReference. But that's another problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you use container DataSource, it do connection pooling for you.

Connection pooling not depend of RowSet implementation, and rowset should be closed after use. I suggest to read it immediatly into array of plain object and close. And don't use `JdbcRowSetImpl`, `RowSet` will be enough.

EDIT:
 i forget to answer your question: Check how many connection you have in pool, than in loop call getConnection and execute select, and *do not close* `ResultSet`. You get error when you reach count open connection == configured max open connection in connection pool.

Comment: THANK!  Got the answer on the Connection Pooling!
Can I summarize that:

voRS = (RowSet)(proConnection.createStatement()).executeQuery(pvsSQLText);

Will do the trick? It will cast the ResultSet to RowSet?

Comment: um, sorry, my mistake, not RowSet, should be ResultSet of course. executeQuery will always return ResultSet, you can fetch it manually, it has methods next() and getters of various type to read current row values.

Answer (score 0):

get the `JDBC  connection object`

```
 System.out.println(conn.getClass().getName());
```

Comment: It says: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection
But wouldn't the problem be: (voConn.createStatement()).executeQuery(pvsSQLText) ?
Here, it is using the createStatement() which returns a ResultSet. This ResultSet is "bad" as compared to JdbcRowSet right (ResultSet doesn't use connection pooling)?  hence I cast it to JdbcRowSet. But would this casting work?

Comment: Checked this: http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/JdbcRowSet.html  .